# An ideal generated by a nontrivial idempotent is not a free module

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, noncommutative-algebra, group-rings

> Let $R = \Bbb QG$ with $G$ isomorphic to a cyclic group of order $2$, and $x$ its generator. I'm trying to show that 
>   $$\frac{1}{2}(1+x)R$$ 
>   is not a free $R$-module.

I found out that $\frac{1}{2}(1+x)\in\Bbb QG\;$ is idempotent but can't go further.

Comment: You probably want to prove the following general fact: if $e$ is a nontrivial idempotent (meaning not equal to 0 or 1) in a ring $R$, then $eR$ is not a free $R$-module.  However, in your case, it is enough to look at $\mathbb{Q}$-dimensions.

Comment: @JiangweiXue, why not add a little and write down your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

$$e(1-e)=0\implies\;\forall\;er\in eR\;,\;\;er\cdot(1-e)=e(1-e)r=0\implies$$

there cannot be any (free) basis for the $\,R$-module $\,eR\,$.